# SSH Proxycommand argument though Python2 subprocess.call

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess

I am scripting with Python some automatic server connection.
To access some servers, I need to proxy the SSH connection.
I have the following errror letting me think it is related to the handling of the ***ProxyCommand*** value:

> /bin/bash: /usr/bin/ncat --proxy 127.0.0.1:9000 --proxy-type socks5
> 10.230.10.5 22: No such file or directory

The associated python code is:

```
cmd = ['ssh', '-t', '-t', '-N', '-f', '-o', "ProxyCommand='/usr/bin/ncat --proxy 127.0.0.1:9000 --proxy-type socks5 %h %p'", '-o', 'ExitOnForwardFailure=yes', '-p', '22', 'root@10.230.10.5']
ret = subprocess.call(cmd)
```

However, when typing such command directly on the server, it works fine:

```
ssh -t -t -N -f -o ProxyCommand='/usr/bin/ncat --proxy 127.0.0.1:9000 --proxy-type socks5 %h %p' -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -p 22 root@10.230.10.5
```

Do you have an idea on how I should handle the ProxyCommand value so that ***bash*** understand it?

Thank you for your help